# Can not correctly open python file to test it.

Tags: python

I just want to open a python file. I went into cmd , set my path to `C:\python33` and typed in `python test.py` and I got this error:

```
python: can't open file 'test.py": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But there IS a file. Is it supposed to be inside the python33 file? because it is right now. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

A second issue is that when I set the path to `C:\python33` it deleted my old path. Is this a problem? How do I find out what the old path was and how to I have more than one path? (as you can tell I am VERY new to all of this and just want to understand it.

Comment: Is `test.py` in the working directory? Also, usually you just want to *add* things to your path, rather than replacing it. Within a single command prompt, though, it's not a problem.

Comment: Did you restart your shell after changing you PATH ?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python33
```

Then change to the directory where `test.py` is, doing:

```
cd C:\Python33 # or somewhere else
```

and execute `python test.py`

Comment: What do you mean"go to the directory". in cmd, I should just write python test.py, right. Or am I supposed to write "python test.py" somewhere else?

Comment: just adding... you should create another folder to pu `test.py` in, like `C:\Temp`

Comment: I'm sorry I feel so stupid! What do you mean go to the directory?

Comment: using `cd` means change directory, or change folder... this command works on `cmd`

Comment: thank you all! I understand now. Now I'm just having problems with my code in general. It starts with a print command, which pulls out Syntax Error: invalidsyntax

Comment: OK good! :) ... don't worry asking questions, that's why these communities exist for